# Feature Detection and Feature Descriptor in Image Processing

Tags: image-processing

Well, I am clear about Feature Detection and Feature Descriptor. Feature detection is finding some interesting points in an image and we can describe them by descriptor like SIFT, HoG etc. My doubt is very specific. Suppose I have an image(I), I applied Harris Detector and found  x,y positions of the corners in that image. Now, I want to apply SIFT to find SIFT features so how should I do it ? Should I make a new image with detected corners only and then should apply SIFT over it ? Or SIFT should be applied on image I (but that serves no purpose I guess) ?

Please help me to have some clarity on practical grounds.

Answer (score 0):

The SIFT descriptor, as you say, describes the feature point.  However, SIFT also tries to be scale invariant.  This means that the SIFT detector also examines potential key-points with respect to their response to various scales.  The detector then records not only the `x,y`, but also the scale information.

This means that you're probably better off using the detector that comes with SIFT along with the descriptor.  Both Matlab and OpenCV implementations easily allow you to detect and describe points.

Comment: Sorry, your reply did confuse me. I wanted to know what will be the input image for SIFT ? Also, what if I already compute the Harris points in multiple scales and consider the local maxima as final value? Then, what will be the significance of applying SIFT.

Comment: The input image is the original grayscale image.   The SIFT detector works on multiple scales but selects the scale that gives the best response.  Unless you want to re-implement the SIFT detector, I don't see why you would need to force the use of the Harris corners.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but the picture is still unclear and I would be grateful if I could get some clue. I try to explain you again. I actually read a paper in which after a segmentation step three  types of features were extracted in parallel manner i.e. "Harris-Laplace + SIFT" , "Hessian-Laplace + SIFT" and "Fast Hessian + SIFT". So what role this "+" operator is playing ? I mean, you said to apply SIFT on original image and Harris-Laplace will also would be applied on original image so how to combine both of them ?

Comment: I don't know what the original paper authors were trying to do.  Perhaps they also calculated which scale, or perhaps they were using a fixed value for scale.   It is possible to calculate a SIFT descriptor for a detected feature point, given the original image + position, but the result is less likely to be invariant to scale.